# Error: oauth_token_secret is deprecated

Tags: ruby, ssl, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to use the Oauth gem to access the Twitter API so I can make a twitter bot, following this tutorial: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/microblogger.html
I got a pin-number from Twitter and entered it. But it failed somehow.
Here's the error I'm getting when I run the program:

```
Initializing MicroBlogger
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jumpstart_auth-0.4.0/lib/ju
mpstart_auth.rb:44:in `block in twitter': [DEPRECATION] #oauth_token= is depreca
ted. Use #access_token= instead.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jumpstart_auth-0.4.0/lib/ju
mpstart_auth.rb:45:in `block in twitter': [DEPRECATION] #oauth_token_secret= is
deprecated. Use #access_token_secret= instead.
```

I'm using windows 7, with Ruby version 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update jumpstart-auth to current version 0.6.0

https://rubygems.org/gems/jumpstart_auth

In this version 0.6.0 it is access_token and not oauth_token anymore.

Comment: Thank you sir, that error annoyed me and now it's gone :)